# MySQL doesn't CSV-import \N as NULL

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a CSV file into a MySQL 5.1 DB using phpMyAdmin. The file includes several date columns which may contain `NULL` values. [According to the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), `NULL` should be written as `\N`. However, after an otherwise successful import, `\N` appears as `0000-00-00` in the date columns (as opposed to *`NULL`*). How do I get NULLs imported?

Options set:

- line separator `,`
- fields enclosed by `"`,
- fields escaped by `\`,
- lines terminated by `auto`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

phpMyAdmin distinguishes two CSV import formats: `CSV` and `CSV with LOAD DATA`. The latter option actually accepts `\N` as described in the manual.

If columns are enclosed by a character (as it is the case), NULLs may also be imported using the former method (no `LOAD DATA`) by setting a value to a non-enclosed `NULL` in the CSV file. This is in accordance with the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)'s following statement:

> If FIELDS ENCLOSED BY is not empty, a field containing the literal
>   word NULL as its value is read as a NULL value. This differs from the
>   word NULL enclosed within FIELDS ENCLOSED BY characters, which is read
>   as the string 'NULL'.